# How does "FOO= myprogram" in bash make "if(getent("FOO"))" return true in C?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I recently ran into a C program that makes use of an environmental variable as a flag to change the behavior of a certain part of the program:

```
if (getenv("FOO")) do_this_if_foo();
```

You'd then request  the program by prepending the environment variable, **but without actually setting it to anything**:

`FOO= mycommand myargs`

Note that the intention of this was to trigger the flag - if you didn't want the added operation, you just wouldn't include the `FOO=`. However, I've never seen an environment variable set like this before. Every example I can find of prepended variables sets a value, `FOO=bar mycommand myargs`, rather than leaving it empty like that.

What exactly is happening here, that allows this flag to work without being set? And are there potential issues with implementing environmental variables like this?

Comment: What's happening here is that `FOO=` assigns the empty string to `FOO`. That means your code doesn't actually work because it just checks for the existence of `FOO`, not whether it's empty.

Comment: So it's equivalent to FOO=""? I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't work" - it's not my code, and it does work, which is why I asked about it. But if it sets equal to an empty string, that's not null, which I assume would be why the check functions. Would you like to add it as an answer?

Comment: Oh, you mean you intend to "doathing"? Then yes, the empty string will work, just like any other value.

Comment: Yes. What did you feel the code implied? I'd like to correct it before I get downvoted any further.

Comment: ...if you wanted to *unset* it, you'd want `(unset FOO; exec mycommand myargs)`, which actually removes `FOO` from the environment should it be there; the parens scope the change to a subshell, and the `exec` consumes that subshell so you don't have extra performance hit from its prior creation.

Comment: I thought you were trying to *not* `doathing()`, i.e. unset `FOO` for the execution of `mycommand`. For that you'd have to `(unset FOO; mycommand ...)` or `env -u FOO mycommand`.

Comment: That said, whether by "equal to nothing" you mean "set to an empty string" or "unset" is very unclear. I can see someone choosing to downvote on those grounds.

Comment: @melpomene, unless you `exec` the `mycommand` you're eating the cost of an extra `fork()` in that formulation (unless your version of bash happens to optimize it out, but that optimization happens only if all the stars align wrt. active runtime flags &c).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, but with `exec` you're eating the cost of hitting 5 extra keys, which takes about 1000 times longer than a single `fork`.

Comment: Given as 50 forks/sec is not unheard of, I gather you're a pretty slow typist. :)

Comment: I've edited the question to clear up the set/unset ambiguity.

Comment: I've edited the title to try to be more explicit about your question; hopefully that'll stop the downvotes and lead to more directly useful answers.

Comment: BTW, note that the other thing I did was to try to rephrase the title to more explicitly be a *question* -- not just describing what your question is *about*, but making the title actually encapsulate the specific problem you wanted an answer to; it's a good guideline to follow in general.

Comment: I'll be more attentive to that in the future. I was a bit fixated on the "set to nothing" as a search/description term, but the real core of the question was why it was evaluating to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) says:

> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
>
> ```
> name=[value]
> ```
>
> If *value* is not given, the variable is assigned the null string.

Note that "null" (in the sense of e.g. JavaScript `null`) is not a thing in the shell. When the bash manual says "null string", it means an empty string (i.e. a string whose length is zero).

[Also](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion):

> When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.
>
> [...]
>
> If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the current shell environment. Otherwise, the variables are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell environment.

So all `FOO= mycommand` does is set the environment variable `FOO` to the empty string while executing `mycommand`. This satisfies `if (getenv("FOO"))` because it only checks for the presence of the variable, not whether it has a (non-empty) value.

Of course, any other value would work as well: `FOO=1 mycommand`, `FOO=asdf mycommand`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`FOO=` is just setting the variable to null (to be precise it's setting the variable to a zero-byte string, which thus returns a pointer to a NUL terminator - thanks @CharlesDuffy). Given the code you posted it could be `FOO='bananas'`and produce the same behavior. It's very odd to write code that way though. The common reason to set a variable on the command line is to pass a value for that variable into the script, e.g. to set debugging or logging level flags is extremely common, e.g. (pseudocode):

```
debug=1 logLevel=3 myscript

myscript() {
    if (debug == 1) {
        if (loglevel > 0) {
            printf "Entering myscript()\n" >> log
            if (logLevel > 1) {
                printf "Arguments: %s\n" "$*" >> log
            }
        }
    }
    do_stuff()
}
```

Having just a "variable exists" test is a bit harder to work with because then you have to specifically unset the variable to clear the flag instead of just setting `FOO=1` when you want to do something and otherwise your script doesn't care when FOO is null or 0 or unset or anything else.

Comment: "Setting the variable to null" is pretty unclear. "Setting the variable to a zero-byte string, which thus returns a pointer to a NUL terminator" would be more explicit. (Compare to `getent()` actually returning NULL instead of that pointer, as happens is the case when there's no variable set at all).

Comment: I would note that this code was specifically written as a "hack" by its creator, to add last minute support for a feature while avoiding breaking other parts of a 2500 line program. I was confused by the bash manual because it said it'd return NULL, and so it didn't make sense to me that `getenv()` of a null value would return true. I misunderstood that it was the null *string*.